# Alert for centos7 kernel update

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, kernel, monitoring

I would like to know how to set an alert on our monitoring tool, Whenever there is an update availbale for centos7 kernel version in Redhat site or in centos site..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

With `yum updateinfo list updates` you can list all available updates.

You can parse the output in a script and include it in your monitoring. The "System Up-To-Date monitor (APT / YUM)" chapter at https://www.logix.cz/michal/devel/nagios/ might be useful to you (even if not using Nagios)